# How to install fspy(camera matching software) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, blender

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I tried to install fspy (camera matching software in which we use real time modeling) on Ubuntu 18.04 but it didn't work.
I downloaded the required files from [Github repository](https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy) 
then I used the command line `sudo apt install fspy`. 
But when I tried to open the software, it has only the python scripts.
How can I install fspy(camera matching software) on my Ubuntu 18.04?
What command lines should I use to install it?

Comment: Check this [link](https://discourse.appimage.org/t/how-to-run-an-appimage/80) and this [one](https://appimage.github.io/fSpy/) too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Download the fspy from github via this [link](https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy/releases/download/v1.0.3/fspy-1.0.3-x86_64.AppImage)
2. Make the program executable by running this command in your terminal (you have to open your terminal in the folder containing the the downloaded file): `chmod +x ./*.AppImage`
   **Or** you can do it as showed in the GIF:
   Right click on the downloaded file, go to **Properties>Permissions**, then check *Allow executing file as program*.

[image]

3. Now fspy is ready to be used, just double click on it and it will work.

Comment: thank you so much it has worked!